# how to export multiple html tables to excel with single id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, excel, dom

I am having two html tables which are coming dynamically with different data. Not able to export both to excel sheet i am willing to export single table.

```
<div class="data" style="display: block;">

    <table id="testTable" border="1">
    <tbody>
    <table style="width:300px">
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>      
      <td>80</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
    </table>

</div>
<div class="data" style="display: block;">

    <table id="testTable" border="1">
    <tbody>
    <table style="width:300px">
    <tr>
      <td>vsr</td>
      <td>sub</td>      
      <td>90</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
    </table>

</div>
```

like this my table comes with different set of data from db

my js code is

```
var tableToExcel = (function() {
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape((s))) }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }

  return function(table, name, filename) {
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(resultarea)
    var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: resultarea.innerHTML}

    document.getElementById("dlink").href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
    document.getElementById("dlink").download = filename;
    document.getElementById("dlink").click();

  }
})()
```

not able to export to excel same time both table data. Please help me.

Comment: same ids are not going to work, use classname instead or change to different ids with appending/prepending something like `1,2,3 etc.`.

Answer (score 0):

You should reference by classname, not by id. Using the same id for more than one HTML element is not recommended for exactly the kind of error you're running into now.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<form id="picsform" name="picsform">
 <div class="formHeader">
 <table>
 <tr>
 <td style="width: 170px; height:40px;" class="nobdrLtMid">reserved for company logo</td>
 <td class="formTitle" style="width: 650px;">PIC/S Checklist</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td class="nobdrRtMid" style="padding-left: 170px;">
 <label for="Company">Company:</label>
 </td>
 <td class="nobdrLtMid" style="width: 200px;">
 <input class="nobdrLtMid" type="text" id="Company" name="Company" title="Company" style="width: 100%">
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 <div class="clearBoth"></div>
 <table style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
 <tr>
 <td class="nobdrRtMid" style="width: 100px;">
 <label for="form.number">Form Number:</label>
 </td>
 <td class="nobdrLtMid" style="width: 125px;">
 <input name="form.number" type="text" class="textfield" id="form.number" title="Form Number" style="width:100%;" />
 </td>
 <td class="nobdrRtMid" style="width: 100px;">
 <label for="form.created">Date Created:</label>
 </td>
 <td class="nobdrLtMid" style="width: 125px;">
 <input name="form.created" type="text" class="textfield" id="form.created" title="Date Created" style="width:100%;" />
 </td>
 <td class="nobdrRtMid" style="width: 100px;">
 <label for="form.creatorname">Created By:</label>
 </td>
 <td class="nobdrLtTop" style="width: 150px;">
 <input name="form.creatorname" type="text" id="form.creatorname" class="textfield" title="Creator Name" style="width:100%;">
 </td>
 <td class="nobdrRtMid" style="width: 100px;">
 <label for="route.stepname">Current Step:</label>
 </td>
 <td class="nobdrLtMid" style="width: 150px;">
 <input name="route.stepname" type="text" class="textfield" id="route.stepname" title="Current Route Step" style="width:100%;" />
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 <div class="clearboth"></div> <a id="dlink" style="display:none;"></a>

 <div class="toolbar no-print" style="padding-left: 390px;">
 <button class="tlb-btn toolbarBluebtn reset" style="margin-left:3px">Reset</button>
 <input type="button" class="tlb-btn toolbarGreenbtn submit" style="margin-left:12px" id="submit" name="submit" title="submit" value="Submit Form" />
 <input id="ExporttoExcel" class="show" type="button" onclick="toExcel()" value="Export to Excel">
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="sectionData">
 <table class="table" id="table" border="2">
 <tbody>
 <tr>
 <th class="allbdrCenMidBld" style="width: 155px;">Topic</th>
 <th class="allbdrCenMidBld" style="width: 730px;">Question:</th>
 <th class="allbdrCenMidBld" style="width: 30px;">OK</th>
 <th class="allbdrCenMidBld" style="width: 35px;">NOK</th>
 <th class="allbdrCenMidBld" style="width: 30px;">N/A</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td class="allbdrCenTop">Introduction</td>
 <td class="allbdrLtMid">Please provide the following information:
 <br>&nbsp;
 <input type="checkbox" id="Gen01O1" name="Gen01O1">&nbsp;
 <label for="Gen01O1">- Company introduction</label>
 <br>&nbsp;
 <input type="checkbox" id="Gen01O2" name="Gen01O2">&nbsp;
 <label for="Gen01O2">- Product list</label>
 <br>&nbsp;
 <input type="checkbox" id="Gen01O3" name="Gen01O3">&nbsp;
 <label for="Gen01O3">- Latest audit results from authority</label>
 <br>&nbsp;
 <input type="checkbox" id="Gen01O4" name="Gen01O4">&nbsp;
 <label for="Gen01O4">- Next schedule for audit</label>
 </td>
 <td class="allbdrCenTop">
 <input type="radio" id="rb_GEN_01a" name="rb_GEN_01" value="OK" />
 </td>
 <td class="allbdrCenTop">
 <input type="radio" id="rb_GEN_01b" name="rb_GEN_01" value="NOK" />
 </td>
 <td class="allbdrCenTop">
 <input type="radio" id="rb_GEN_01c" name="rb_GEN_01" value="NA" />
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="CGEN_01" style="display: none">
 <td colspan="5">
 <input id="ComGEN_01" type="text" value="" class="nobdrLtTopBl" placeholder="Comment on deficiency:" style="width:100%;" name="ComGEN_01" title="Com GEN 01" />
 </td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
 </div>
 <div class="sectionData">
 <table class="table" id="table" border="2">
 <tbody>
 <tr>
 <th class="allbdrCenMidBld" style="width: 155px;">Topic</th>
 <th class="allbdrCenMidBld" style="width: 730px;">Question:</th>
 <th class="allbdrCenMidBld" style="width: 30px;">OK</th>
 <th class="allbdrCenMidBld" style="width: 35px;">NOK</th>
 <th class="allbdrCenMidBld" style="width: 30px;">N/A</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td class="allbdrCenTop">RM receiving</td>
 <td class="allbdrLtMid">Visual inspection receipt bay condition.</td>
 <td class="allbdrCenTop">
 <input type="radio" id="rb_WHS_01a" name="rb_WHS_01" value="OK" />
 </td>
 <td class="allbdrCenTop">
 <input type="radio" id="rb_WHS_01b" name="rb_WHS_01" value="NOK" />
 </td>
 <td class="allbdrCenTop">
 <input type="radio" id="rb_WHS_01c" name="rb_WHS_01" value="NA" />
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="CWHS_01" style="display: none">
 <td colspan="5">
 <input id="ComWHS_01" type="text" value="" class="nobdrLtTopBl" placeholder="Comment on deficiency:" style="width:100%;" name="ComWHS_01" title="Com WHS 01" />
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td class="allbdrCenTop"></td>
 <td class="allbdrLtMid">Do you have SOP to check received materials conditions including container management (e.g. damaged container, check against delivery note, quality, identity, conformity)?</td>
 <td class="allbdrCenTop">
 <input type="radio" id="rb_WHS_02a" name="rb_WHS_02" value="OK" />
 </td>
 <td class="allbdrCenTop">
 <input type="radio" id="rb_WHS_02b" name="rb_WHS_02" value="NOK" />
 </td>
 <td class="allbdrCenTop">
 <input type="radio" id="rb_WHS_02c" name="rb_WHS_02" value="NA" />
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="CWHS_02" style="display: none">
 <td colspan="5">
 <input id="ComWHS_02" type="text" value="" class="nobdrLtTopBl" placeholder="Comment on deficiency:" style="width:100%;" name="ComWHS_02" title="Com WHS 02" />
 </td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
 </div>
</form>
<script>
 $('input:radio').live('change', function(){
 var sstrSect = ($(this).attr('name').substr([3]));
 var comFldId = ("C" + sstrSect);
 if ($(this).val() == "NOK"){
 document.getElementById(comFldId).style.display = '';
 } else {
 document.getElementById(comFldId).style.display = 'none';
 }
 });

 $('input[type="radio"]:checked').each(function() {
 var sstrSect = ($(this).attr('name').substr([3]));
 var comFldId = ("C" + sstrSect);
 if ($(this).val() == "NOK"){
 document.getElementById(comFldId).style.display = '';
 } else {
 document.getElementById(comFldId).style.display = 'none';
 }
 });

function toExcel() {

 if ("ActiveXObject" in window) {
 alert("This is Internet Explorer!");
 } else {

 var cache = {};
 this.tmpl = function tmpl(str, data) {
 var fn = !/\W/.test(str) ? cache[str] = cache[str] || tmpl(document.getElementById(str).innerHTML) :
 new Function("obj",
 "var p=[],print=function(){p.push.apply(p,arguments);};" +
 "with(obj){p.push('" +
 str.replace(/[\r\t\n]/g, " ")
 .split("{{").join("\t")
 .replace(/((^|}})[^\t]*)'/g, "$1\r")
 .replace(/\t=(.*?)}}/g, "',$1,'")
 .split("\t").join("');")
 .split("}}").join("p.push('")
 .split("\r").join("\\'") + "');}return p.join('');");
 return data ? fn(data) : fn;
 };
 var tableToExcel = (function () {
 var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
 template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{{=worksheet}}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body>{{for(var i=0; i<tables.length;i++){ }}<table>{{=tables[i]}}</table>{{ } }}</body></html>',
 base64 = function (s) {
 return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)));
 },
 format = function (s, c) {
 return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) {
 return c[p];
 });
 };
 return function (tableList, name) {
 if (!tableList.length > 0 && !tableList[0].nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table);
 var tables = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < tableList.length; i++) {
 tables.push(tableList[i].innerHTML);
 }
 var ctx = {
 worksheet: name || 'Worksheet',
 tables: tables
 };
 window.location.href = uri + base64(tmpl(template, ctx));
 };
 })();
 tableToExcel(document.getElementsByTagName("table"), "one");
 }
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I export multiple table wirh the same id and its work perfectly!!